# How can I fix this jQuery message bar function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function loader_bar(msg,msgtype) {


      switch (msgtype) {
        case 'error':
            $class = 'bar_error topbar'
            break;
        case 'success':
            $class = 'bar_success topbar'
            break;
        case 'working':
            $class = 'topbar'
            msg = 'Spinner ' + msg
            break;
        default:
            $class = 'topbar'
            msg = msg
            break;
      }

     if ($("#loader_bar").is(":visible")) {
         $("#loader_bar").removeClass()
         clearInterval(int);
         $("#loader_bar").html(msg).addClass($class);
    } else {
      $('<div />', { "class": $class, html: msg, "id" : "loader_bar" }).prependTo("body").slideDown('fast');    
    }

      myTimer = setInterval($("#loader_bar").slideUp('fast'), 10000);
}
```

Right now, it appears for a split second then goes?

Basically I want a bar to appear with a certain class when I call it, after 10 seconds I want it to `slideUp` however if it is called again from another function before the timeout. I want to reset the timer and change the message / class and keep it up another 10 seconds...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myTimer = setInterval($("#loader_bar").slideUp('fast'), 10000);
```

should be

```
myTimer = setInterval(function() { $("#loader_bar").slideUp('fast'); }, 10000);
```

The statement to run must be in a function, otherwise it would be called instantly.

Comment: Also, I see no reason why this should be `setInterval()` rather than `setTimeout()`.  Once `.slideUp()` has been called, there's no reason to call it again and again.